# How to compile boost faster?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, boost, compilation

I'm using the following command on Win7 x64

```
.\b2 --cxxflags=/MP --build-type=complete
```

also tried

```
.\b2 --cxxflags=-MP --build-type=complete
```

However, cl.exe is still using only one of the 8 cores of my system.Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure you need a complete build? Most of Boost is headers only. And if you need to compile some specific parts, you just need to do it once...

Comment: @Macmade Agreed. However, I found the slow compilation really really annoying for some reason :)

Comment: Did you consider using Linux, and `make -j` ? It might be interesting to you

Comment: @Macmade and then there are build servers or virtual development environments for QA. Compiling the libraries can take hours so yes, optimizing it is worth a little

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch except that `make` doesn't work for Boost (are you referring to experimental CMake support?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the compilation parallel at the  build tool level, not per translation unit with

```
.\b2 -j8
```

or similar (if you have n cores, `-j(n+1)` is often used)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Malwarebytes was the culprit. It was slowing down the compilation by scanning newly generated files and memory. I turned it off, now I'm seeing 50% utilization(4 cores) sometimes. It's still between 5%-14% most of the time though.